# Looking for low-mid phone with good battery & screen

Tags: android, mobile-phone, battery-life, battery

I need a new phone to replace a Moto G7 Power that I dropped in a lake. I would buy it again but I can't find it anywhere for near its original price (I saw one on eBay for £250, double its original price). I'd like to find a similar phone for a similar price of £100-£200. Requirements in order of how important they are to me:

- Good battery life. Moti G7 Power had 5000mAh which admittedly is overkill, but the more the better (>=4000mAh would be nice)
- decent screen: Moto G7 Power had a 720p 19:9 display which was probably it's weakest point, a 1080p screen would be nice but I'll compromise on the screen if necessary.
- Relatively stock android: so not Samsung, I want a pretty standard version like that of Motorola phones. Android 9 is my OS of choice because it's relatively recent but also still has the old-school navigation buttons that i can't live without.
- USB-C: is very cool
- Decently fast processor, basically anything will do to be honest, and enough graphics power to play 1080p60 YouTube smoothly (probably not even necessary to specify)

Thanks for any and all suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I suggest the Moto G7 Power?

Despite what the question indicates, I was able to find several sites where it is being offered for less than £200, including eBay.

[Here](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Motorola-G7-Power-6-2-64GB-12MP-4GB-Dual-sim-Unlocked-Smartphone-Black/124235176292?epid=20029779493&hash=item1cecfe5964:g:EwEAAOSw8Xpe9FE0) is a refurbished one for only 143. [Here](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Motorola-Moto-G7-Power-64GB-4GB-6-2-Dual-SIM-4G-LTE-GSM-Unlocked-XT1955-4/143691899031?epid=19032626436&hash=item2174b46097:g:SVMAAOSw7URfQEAW)
is a completely new one from about 125.

The [Motorola store in the US](https://www.motorola.com/us/smartphones-moto-g7-power/p)
is definitely still selling it for $179 (£134). If you have a friend in the US they can mail it to you. Careful of possible international version differences.

Alternately, you can go for the [G8 Power Lite](https://www.motorola.co.uk/smartphones-moto-g-power-lite-gen-8/p), which is being sold for £130 on Motorola's UK site. You'll see improvements in almost everything over the G7 Power, except that 4K video recording may not be possible, and it has an unusual processor, something that might affect battery life.

You could even get the regular G8 Power for under 200 on Amazon if you are willing to go for a used, like-new device.  Lenovo UK is also selling them new for 200 (limited time discount coupon). This will be an improvement in all aspects over your previous device, except that a higher resolution may decrease battery life.  It would come with Android 10, unfortunately.

Comment: Wait a sec, how did you find that one on eBay? If I search I just can't find it. Anyway assuming that it is legit (I've had some bad experiences with eBay in the past) then that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I would personally get the newer model.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you mentioned feels like Xiamomi phones should do the work. You can get Mi 8 lite for ~£200

size: 156.40 x 75.80 x 7.50 mm

screen: 1080 x 2280 px (6.26") 403 ppi

battery: Li-Ion 3350 mAh (yes, it's lower than you wanted but it's hard to squish power and a good battery to make it under 200 GBP)

CPU: Qualcomm Snapdragon 660

Including Android 10 and USB-C cable

Or Moto G9 / Moto G8. They are similliar to that one you had before.

Comment: Yeah battery life is a bit low to be honest